# systemd: spawn gettys ASAP

Tags: systemd, getty

Normally `systemd` will spawn a `getty` on the virtual terminals just before it starts graphical mode.

I have always thought that is the wrong time to spawn a `getty`: The time when you need the `getty` is when the booting fails, and it needs a helping hand to get back.

How do I change the order, so `getty` is spawned as soon as `root` can login?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out `man systemd-debug-generator`. It is talking about boot options, but says you can also enable the feature permanently, as for any service:

> If the `systemd.debug-shell` option is specified, the debug shell service
>       "debug-shell.service" is pulled into the boot transaction. It will
>       spawn a debug shell on tty9 during early system startup. Note that the
>       shell may also be turned on persistently by enabling it with
>       systemctl(1)'s enable command.

Comment: Is there a way to make this into a getty? So that it can be permanently enabled without leaving an open root login?

Comment: Presumably, you can override the `ExecStart=/sbin/sushell` in `/usr/lib/systemd/system/debug-shell.service` using the usual systemd mechanisms, and replace it by a line similar to what is in `getty@.service`, replacing the `%I` by tty9.